# Queries execute faster when hosted on laptop than on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-access, iis, windows-server-2012

I am experiencing a strange issue when publishing an ASP MVC application to Windows Server 2012.

The app is fairly simple, and on most of the pages visited it will query an Access database which is hosted on the server.

I noticed that the queries are quite slow (often taking between 7-10 seconds to complete), as shown when running the app with MiniProfiler.

As a simple test, I decided to host the app on my Windows 10 laptop to see if there was a difference, and it is much faster (Most queries are under 200ms).

This is what I tried so far:

- Match advanced Application Pool settings
- Match Firewall settings
- Enabled link local multicast name resolution (LLMNR)
- Confirmed that ODBC tracing is disabled (32 and 64)
- Moved the Access Backoffice.mdb file to the server's C drive (same as on the laptop)
- Made sure web.config match (apart from connectionString Data Source)
- Added `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website` and `C:\Test\Database` to antivirus scan exclusions
- Increased the `MaxBufferSize` key value from 0 in `Access Connectivity Engine` in the registry

Does anyone know of a way that I can try debugging this issue, or any possible solutions?

**notes**

Both my laptop and the server are on the same network while testing this, and I am accessing the app from an ipad.

I am also experiencing the same slowness when using the application from a browser on the server itself (url = 10.0.0.1 or localhost)

When I execute the exact same query code from a console app on the server, it runs a lot faster (on par with the laptop). I am only experiencing this issue via the asp app.

#### Laptop Details:

- Processor : Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
- RAM       : 16.0 GB
- OS        : Windows 10 x64

#### Server Details

- Processor : Intel Xeon CPU E5-2603 v4 @ 1.70GHz (2 processors)
- RAM       : 32.0 GB
- OS        : Windows Server 2012 x64

**Connection String**

I have tried the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=W:\My Backoffice.mdb
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Test\My Backoffice.mdb
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\ServerName\W\My Backoffice.mdb
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\ServerName\C\Test\My Backoffice.mdb
```

With both `16.0` and `12.0` as the `ACE.OLEDB` version, where W is a Local server drive which is used as a network share acrcoss the domain. All of these gave the same result.

Comment: Hello. Is it the query itself slow or your page loading ? Also what are the stats of the server? Like traffic etc.

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos I wrapped the function which executes the query in a `MiniProfiler` to confirm that this is where the application is slow. The server is pretty much only used to host an MS Access system and is used by no more than ~20 people at any given time. When using the Access system itself, the database runs fine and is not slow at all (users have a front-end `accdb` file on their computers which accesses the backend on the server)

Comment: can you show the connection string ? The server address part. At a point i had the same problem because my connection string was going on a callback cycle. (It was going out the router and back to the server)

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos Do you happen to know any resources where I can check whether my situation is similar to yours? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: From the connection strings that you provided  this is not the case. Because i see you provide a file path. In my case i had ip address like `Data Source=10.10.23.55,1564` I would try in your case to do a simple ADO.NET call to check connectivity. Also i would try to monitor the server for any spikes at the time of the call to the database.